# Which one to use "a major part of" or "the major part of"?

Tags: grammar

When do we use "a" or "the" before "major part of" or just "part of"?

as in the examples of:
"I use the major part of my energy on studies"
"I use a major part of my energy on studies"

Comment: 'The major part of' means 'most of'. 'A major part of' means 'a very significant part of'.

Comment: Thank you. What's the difference between "most of" and "a very significant part of"?

By the way how the function differs between using the equation mark of " and ' ?

Comment: I would consider 40% of a billion pounds a very significant part of the whole. // I usually use single quotes other than for actual direct speech. There are other conventions, and even people saying 'this is the way it's done in the UK' (here I'm giving a paraphrase rather than an actual quote I've seen) etc. They often mean 'should be done'. But conventions are not binding, especially when different ones exist. // It _does_ get difficult in threads where different conventions are in use.